# Heat equation with specific boundary conditions

Tags: heat-conduction

I am interested in a specific problem of 1-dim. heat transfer.

A rod (metal) with coordinate $0 \le x \le d$  of length d is in contact with two reservoirs $i = 1,2$ with fixed temperatures $T_1 < T_2$. The initial condition for the rod reads

$$ T(0 \le x \le d, t=0) = T_1 $$

The $T_1$ reservoir (ice water) at $x < 0$ fixes the temperature

$$ T(x=0, t \ge 0) = T_1 $$

From the $T_2$ reservoir (hot air) at $x > d$ heat is transferred through the boundary at $x = d$ so that the temperature at $x=d$ will rise:

$$ T(x=d, t > 0) > T_1 $$

One could model this slightly different by fixing

$$ T(x=d, t \ge 0) = T_2 $$

and just using the heat equation with these *fixed* boundary conditions. I doubt this is realistic for small heat transfer coefficient between the $T_2$ reservoir an the rod. I would prefer to combine the heat equation with the heat transfer through the boundary.

How can one extended the heat equation to model this heat transfer through the boundary? What is an appropriate method for a solution?

Extension: a more specific idea is to combine the heat equation in the bulk $0 \le x \le d$

$$ \left[\partial_t - a_\text{bulk} \partial_x^2\right] T(x,t) = 0 $$

with the heat transport through the surface between the bulk and the reservoir

$$ \partial_t T(d,t) - b_\text{surface}\left[T(d) - T_2 \right] = 0 $$

How can this be achieved?

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HeatEqnNonZero.aspx gives you the full solution

Comment: Thanks. I did this calculation myself but I still don't think the approach is realistic. Take a piece of metal with you into the sauna. What temperature is the surface after one minute? Certainly significantly lower than the ambient temperature.

Comment: Tom, don't make life hard for yourself. What I describe is the **spirit** of the question. Looking for how much heat is transferred at the hot end is IMPOSSIBLE without a whole lot more information that you simply don't have.

Comment: And how would you model heat transfer to a rod with no $x$ or $z$ dimensions??

Comment: *What temperature is the surface after one minute?* Sure. And what would be the temperature after 1 hour? Given enough time the rod's end will of course end up at $T_2$, so the argument is moot.

Comment: See equation 2.38 [here](http://www.ingaero.uniroma1.it/attachments/2176_Cap_2%201D%20heat%20conduction%20problems.pdf) for a solution that incorporates convection at either end. I'm not going to bother retyping it as an answer unless it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Chemomechanics' link does indeed describe what you're after. It also shows whether finding transient solutions where the cap temperatures are not constant because of convection is really worth the hassle. In my extended experience of solving such problems the answer is a firm 'NO!' The caps will eventually settle to a given, fixed temperature, then a transient or steady state solution can be obtained relatively easily.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks for that link. Bookmarked!

Comment: @Chemomechanics, thanks a lot; looks really very useful.

Comment: @Gert, I am especially looking for small t and $T(x = d/2, t)$, not for the stationary state. Thanks!

Comment: From page 6. that link treats the transient solution. Since as it obtains $T(t,x)$, $T$ is obtained for any $t$ and any $x$.

Comment: Of course. All wanted to say is that I expect some effects especially for the short-time behavior.

Comment: $\partial_t T(d,t) - b_\text{surface}\left[T(d) - T_2 \right] = 0$ makes no sense whatsoever. It's a mishmash between Fourier and Newton (Law of cooling) What you need is Fourier with a boundary condition that reflects convection at $x=d$.

Comment: ok, thx, understood

Answer (score 0):

You're slightly muddling things here.

What the problem states is that for $T(t,x)$ there are non-homogeneous boundary conditions:
$$T(t,0)=T_1$$
and
$$T(t,d)=T_2$$

for ALL times $t$.

You do not need to take into account the heat flow to $x=0$ and $x=d$ because it has already been accounted for.

Your problem statement should include that the rod is completely insulated for $0<x<d$.

The complete solution [can be found at this web page](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HeatEqnNonZero.aspx).

Comment: Yes, the rod shall be insulated. But I *did* specify the initial condition $T(0 \le x \le d, t=0) = T_1$. And I do know the textbook  solution, but I doubt that this ansatz with the boundary condition at $x = d$ is always realistic.

Comment: You shouldn't really call it an Ansatz, that's more reserved for solving PDEs. However the stated problem *is what it is*. You can't really argue with it. You could run an experiment with an insulated copper rod, one end in ice water, the other in boiling water, if you want something more 'realistic'/

Comment: Du kannst mir gerne glauben, dass die Übersetzung einer Textaufgabe in mathematische Formeln als Ansatz bezeichnet wird ;-)  Ok, let’s call it a model. I am asking not for the solution of this model - which is standard textbook - but for a different model.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific. What presisely do you want to model? What do you want to learn? What are the physical quantities you want including in the model? It should be subject to a new question, IMO.

Comment: Ok, thanks, question slightly extended.